# Faster way to read a file line by line in perl

Tags: perl

I have to read a big unix file line by line using perl. the script is taking more than 2 mins to run in case of big file but takes lesser time for small file.

I am using following code:

```
open(FILE , "filename");

while ( < FILE > ){ 

}
```

Please let me know a way to parse file faster

Comment: What is inside the `while` loop? Do you need to look at *every* line of the file?

Comment: yes i need to look into every line of file.

Comment: Can you determine if you are bottlenecked on disk throughput or processing time? ie what is the running time of your script versus `time cat filename > /dev/null` Don't forget to take disk caching into account, so run each command a few times and take the last result. If your script is substantially slower than `cat`, we'll need to see your processing code (the contents of your while loop)

Comment: What makes you think it's reading a line that takes long?!?!

Comment: Exactly how big is your file? Telling us that it's "big" doesn't help much. You should be able to read through a 12GB file in two minutes. Is it smaller/bigger than that?

Comment: please show us your code inside `while` loop. also, the way you open the file is not recommended, according to the `open` documentation, a more suitable way is  `open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt")` , you should also add `or die "Can't open < input.txt: $!";` to catch errors

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by a "big file" and a "small file"? What size are those files? How many lines do they have?

Unless your big file is absolutely huge, it seems likely that what is slowing your program down is not the reading from a file, but whatever you're doing in the `while` loop. To prove me wrong, you'd just need to run your program with nothing in the while loop to see how long that takes.

Assuming that I'm right, then you need to work out what section of your processing is causing the problems. Without seeing that code we, obviously, can't be any help there. But that's where a tool like [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) would be useful.

I'm not sure where you learned your Perl from, but the idiom you're using to open your file is rather outdated. These days we would a) use lexical variables as filehandles, b) use the 3-argument version of `open()` and c) always check the return value from `open()` and take appropriate action.

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'filename')
  or die "Cannot open 'filename': $!\n";

while ( < $fh > ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the memory, @array = <fh> then look thru array